# Submitting always gets the last value

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <form action="" method="post">
<?php
    include 'Includes/database_connection.php';
    $sql = "select * FROM sims"     ;
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);       
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
        <ul class="category_list">
        <input type="hidden" value="$id1" name="hidden">
        <li><a href="#"><?php echo $row['phonenr'];?><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" name="id"></a></li>

        </ul>

<?php
    }
?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

So i got the above form where you can select phonenumbers and when you submit them a database should be updated. And there are 23 id's in it. After submitting the form it always takes the last value. What am i doing wrong?

```
if(@$_POST ['submit']) 
{  
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    echo $id;
    include 'Includes/database_connection.php';
    mysql_query("UPDATE pairings SET sim_id='$id' 
                            WHERE unit_id='$id1'")
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: ..also, `if(@$_POST ['submit'])` is bad practise. Instead, use `isset($_POST['submit'])` or `empty($_POST['submit'])`. Using `@` to emit an error message is bad practise. You're also injecting SQL into your code.

Answer (score 3):

Change your hidden field name to array like this

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" name="id[]">
```

then on PHP side use loop to retrieve

```
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $val) {
    $id = $val;
    include 'Includes/database_connection.php';
    mysql_query("UPDATE pairings SET sim_id='$id' 
                        WHERE unit_id='$id1'")
}
```

Comment: So i change my hidden field to the array you provided. I tried the foreach thing but i guess i just fail. I get the following message Notice: Array to string conversion in**** on line 64. Line 64 is where i update the database. The following is my foreach code if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  
  foreach ($_POST['id'] as $val){
  $id = $_POST['id'];

Comment: Allright i tried that. I don't get any errors anymore but it still inserts the last value.

Comment: You need to put query also in the foreach loop

Comment: It is in the foreach loop. if(isset($_POST['submit'])){  
  foreach ($_POST['id'] as $val){
  $id = $val;
  include 'Includes/database_connection.php';
  mysql_query("UPDATE pairings SET sim_id='$id' 
        WHERE unit_id='$id1'")
or die(mysql_error()); 
 }
 }

Comment: Can you tell me what is this unit_id='$id1' and where are you getting $id1 variable from?

Comment: $id1 = $_GET["id1"]; It is set on a previous page.

Comment: ok then the result is correct because you are running update query and it will update the row where id =$id1 with last foreach loop value. I think you can try to understand it better. :)

Comment: Yeah that's exacly what it does right now. But it's supposed to update it with the selected value instead of the last.

Comment: Where are you selecting value I do not see a seclect box or something like that?

Comment: Owh yeah i forgot to mention that. Those <li><a> you see around the hidden input field? Those are codes in css as boxes. Which can be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification specified by chandresh_cool, would get the result that you expect.

The input name is replaced with id, so the post key contains only the row[id], not the $_POST['id']

Instead change the name of the hidden field to accept as a array like this

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" name="id[]">
```

Then you can iterate id array as specified by chandresh_cool